# Export Wrapper for slick.session.Database

Tags: database, scala, export, wrapper

I have many queries in the format
`db withSession{ implicit session : Session =>
Q.update[String](query).execute(id)}`
and I want to write it in a much easier way: `db.execute(query, id)`. So, I defined the wrapper in the same file/package where I initialized the `db`.  How can I export the wrapper such that I can use it in this way? Now, I have the Problem `value execute is not a member of scala.slick.session.Database`

Note: query and id are Strings. I use plain sql
db is an already initialized Database:

```
object SQLUtilities{  
  lazy val db = init() 
  private def init() = {Database.forURL("jdbc:postgresql://localhost", driver = "org.postgresql.Driver")}  

  def execute(query: String, id: String){  
    db withSession{ //implicit session : Session =>  
        Q.update[String](query).execute(id)
    }
  } 
}
```

Standard packages like `import scala.slick.jdbc.{GetResult, StaticQuery => Q}; import scala.slick.session.{Session, Database}` are imported

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might be looking for an implicit.  If so, you might want to redefine your SQLUtilities like this:

```
object SQLUtilities{  
  lazy val db = init() 
  private def init() = {Database.forURL("jdbc:postgresql://localhost", driver = "org.postgresql.Driver")}  

  implicit class PimpedDB(val database:Database) extends AnyVal{
    def execute(query: String, id: String){  
      database withSession{ implicit session : Session =>  
          Q.update[String](query).execute(id)
      }
    }    
  }
}
```

Then if you just import `SQLUtilities._` into anywhere you want this pimping applied, you will then gain access to the `execute` function on instances of `Database`.

I apologize in advance if this was not what you were looking for.